# How to fix an error in implementing a quicksort algorithm in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, quicksort

I am working on my understanding of Quicksort in Prolog. This is what I have so far:

```
qsort([],[]):- !.
qsort([X], [X]).
qsort([Head|[Pivot|Tail]],Sorted):-
   split(Pivot,[Head|Tail],Less,Greater),
   qsort(Less,SortedLess),
   qsort(Greater,SortedGreater),
   append(SortedLess,[Pivot|SortedGreater],Sorted).

split(_,[],[],[]).
split(Pivot,[X|T],[X|Less],Greater):-
   X=<Pivot, split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
split(Pivot,[X|T],Less,[X|Greater]):-
   X>Pivot, split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
```

When I try to compile the program, it gives me the following error:

```
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,consult/1)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I pasted your code into [SWI Prolog Online](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) and it works without error for sorting proper grounded lists of integers. Which Prolog system are you using, and how are you compiling it?

Comment: Show the exact query you entered. Most probably you have somehow mangled or forgot round brackets such that finally you had a goal like `[X]`